# “Width equals height” constraint using visual format language

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, visual-format-language

In order to add width equals to its superview height we can do following

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view.superview, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
```

or we can do it from interface builder

[image]

But how can I do the same using VFL?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of [Auto Layout Guide: Visual Format Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage.html)

> The notation prefers good visualization over completeness of
>   expressibility. Most of the constraints that are useful in real user
>   interfaces can be expressed using visual format syntax, but there are
>   a few that cannot. One useful constraint that cannot be expressed is a
>   fixed aspect ratio (for example, imageView.width = 2 *
>   imageView.height). To create such a constraint, you must use
>   `constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:`.

"Width equals Height" is a ratio (to 1). So it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, since that's a pretty uncommon setup. Esoteric use cases like this are where it's best to use the explicit initializer on NSLayoutConstraint.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, the Docs point out that you cannot set certain (common) constraints using VFL. Here's a simple example of adding just **one** additional line to get what you want.

You can run this in a Playground:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport


class TestVC: UIViewController {

    let squareView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .green
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .yellow

        // add the subview
        view.addSubview(squareView)

        //Views to add constraints to
        let views = Dictionary(dictionaryLiteral: ("sqV", squareView))

        // 40 points from left, width of 100
        let horizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-40-[sqV(==100)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
        view.addConstraints(horizontalConstraints)

        // 40 points from top, no height setting
        let verticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-40-[sqV]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
        view.addConstraints(verticalConstraints)

        // set height equal to width (1:1 ratio)
        squareView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: squareView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true

    }

}

let vc = TestVC()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc
```