# How to set dynamic height with Visual Format Language

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint, visual-format-language

```
NSString *format = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-10-[self]-10-|"];
NSString *formatVertical = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|-40-[self(300)]|"];
[constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
[constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:formatVertical options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
```

with formatVertical i am able to set height of my view. But i want to make this value as dynamic to be able to show in all different screens as same look.

Is there anything i can achieve this?

Comment: Do you want it to be a percentage of the superview (the screen)? If so, you cannot do that with VFL

Comment: explain what you exactly mean with dynamic

Comment: If you mean this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47594682/width-equals-height-constraint-using-visual-format-language/47594884#47594884 You can't. But could you explain what you need exactly?

Comment: So, I meant to have universal constraints for all screen sizes (iPhone 5, iPhone X, iPhone 7 etc..) I would like to make my formatVertical as 0.5 of the screen for instance so height will be half size of all screen types no matter how height is the iPhone screens. @DonMag

Comment: Is there any way to apply universal height value for whole different secreen sizes? because if i set as V:|-40-[self(300)]| like this its gonna be so big for iphone5s but a little bit more small for iphone7. @Larme

Comment: @Pat_Morita hello pls take a look my comments i could not tag you it did not allow me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Format Language is nice, except there are a number of layout attributes it cannot do - such as height/width percentages and centering.

The answer from "K. Davydenko" *will* work... sort of. It still sets a fixed height for your subview though. So if you put that in the wrong place (before the superview is laid out, for example), or if the view changes (such as device rotation), you won't get what you're after.

Since it is rather simple to add a `NSLayoutConstraint` in addition to your VFL formatting, that's the better option:

```
UIView *v = [UIView new];
v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
v.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

[self.view addSubview:v];

NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = @{@"self":v};

NSString *format = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-10-[self]-10-|"];

// vertical formatting (40-pts from the top), but do NOT set a height 
// (and do not include the trailing "|")
NSString *formatVertical = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|-40-[self]"];

NSMutableArray *constraints = [NSMutableArray new];

[constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
[constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:formatVertical options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];

// now add a constraint to set the Height of your subview equal to
// the height of the superview, with a 0.5 multiplier
// This will keep your view 1/2 the height of the superview, even
// when the superview's size changes
NSLayoutConstraint *c = [NSLayoutConstraint
                         constraintWithItem:v
                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                         toItem:self.view
                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                         multiplier:0.5
                         constant:0.0];

[constraints addObject:c];

[self.view addConstraints:constraints];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use metrics.
Objective-C solution:

```
NSString *format = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-10-[self]-10-|"];
NSString *formatVertical = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|-40-[self(height)]|"];
NSNumber *height = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.view.frame.size.height / 2];
NSDictionary *metrics = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:height, @"height", nil];
[constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
[constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:formatVertical options:0 metrics:metrics views:viewsDictionary]];
```

Solution for swift from raywenderlich.com:

```
private enum Metrics {
      static let padding: CGFloat = 15.0
      static let iconImageViewWidth: CGFloat = 30.0
    }
let metrics = [
      "horizontalPadding": Metrics.padding,
      "iconImageViewWidth": Metrics.iconImageViewWidth]

let topRowHorizontalFormat = """H:|-horizontalPadding-[iconImageView(iconImageViewWidth)]-[appNameLabel]-[skipButton]-horizontalPadding-|"""
let topRowHorizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
    withVisualFormat: topRowHorizontalFormat,
    options: [.alignAllCenterY],
    metrics: metrics,
    views: views)
allConstraints += topRowHorizontalConstraints

let summaryHorizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
    withVisualFormat: "H:|-horizontalPadding-[summaryLabel]-horizontalPadding-|",
    metrics: metrics,
    views: views)
allConstraints += summaryHorizontalConstraints
```

https://www.raywenderlich.com/174078/auto-layout-visual-format-language-tutorial-2